# How to abort a "new WebSocket" in a client browser

Tags: javascript, caching, https, websocket, auto-versioning

Javascript `new Websocket(socketUrl)` runs on potentially forever if the server refuses to open the websocket, and by design, the surrounding script gets no information on why the server refuses to open it. I have seen client browsers sending websocket requests every few seconds for more than 10 weeks (I suppose a tab has been left open and unused for this whole time).

I have implemented a change in the surrounding client script that detects (via a normal http request) when the websocket requests have become useless, and then closes the socket. From this point onwards, clients who reload their javascript files won't cause problems anymore.

However, I wonder if there is a way to definitely deal with those forgotten tabs in clients who don't ever reload, or if the only thing I can do is to basically treat them like malware by blocking excess requests in the load balancer (haproxy).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your websocket object is named, `websocket_obj`. Like:

```
websocket_obj = new Websocket(url); // url You know it
```

Then, you can close the socket, when you get an error. So,

```
websocket_obj.onerror = function(){
    Websocket.close();
}
```

Here is the [mdn_refs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/close).

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is what I am now already doing in the script when I have detected there is no chance of the websocket request ever succeeding. However, what I am asking is what to do with clients who don't refresh and therefore don't download my new version.

Comment: Just to be clear: I don't want the websocket request to be closed for all types of errors, since it should keep trying if there was e.g. a problem with internet connectivity. It is closed only when I know there is no chance it will ever succeed. But this is already solved. The problem is how to abort the websocket in clients who don't download my new version.